# Is it possible to plot a spline path that follows terrain height in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a terrain that utilizes a heightmap to generate the y position of plane vertices, and I'm also using raycasting to plot meshes on top of it (trees, rocks, etc), and it works great.

What I would like to potentially do now is plot a spline that has each point's y values match the terrain it's drawn on top of. I don't know if I can use raycasting for this (I'm guessing not?), or if there is a way to find the y position from the heightmap itself.

If anyone has any ideas, I'm open!

Here is my terrain and heightmap function if it helps:

Terrain:

```
// TERRAIN
    // load texture
    var textureloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var terrainT = textureloader.load('assets/textures/terrain/Fabric.jpg');
    terrainT.wrapS = terrainT.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    terrainT.repeat.set(4, 4);

    // create terrain from heightmap
    var heightmaploader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
    heightmaploader.load(
        "assets/noisemaps/cloud.png",
        function(img) {

            // read the heightmap and get the vertex data
            data = getHeightData(img);

            var terrainG = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000, 1000, worldWidth - 1, worldDepth - 1);
            terrainG.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

            var vertices = terrainG.attributes.position.array;

            for (var i = 0, j = 0, l = vertices.length; i < l; i++, j += 3) {
                vertices[j + 1] = data[i] * 5;
            }

            terrainG.computeFaceNormals();
            terrainG.computeVertexNormals();

            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                map: terrainT,
                color: 0xffffff
            });

            terrain = new THREE.Mesh(terrainG, material);
            terrain.receiveShadow = true;
            terrain.position.y = -50;
            scene.add(terrain);

            plotAsset('boulder-photo-01.png', 35, 18, terrain);
            plotAsset('boulder-outline-01.png', 25, 20, terrain);
            plotAsset('birch-outline-01.png', 50, 50, terrain);
            plotAsset('tree-photo-01.png', 55, 50, terrain);
            plotAsset('grass-outline-01.png', 25, 20, terrain);
            plotAsset('grass-outline-02.png', 25, 20, terrain);
        }
    );
```

Heightmap:

```
// HEIGHT DATA FROM HEIGHTMAP
function getHeightData(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 2048 / 8;
    canvas.height = 2048 / 8;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var size = canvas.width * canvas.height,
        data = new Float32Array(size);

    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] = 0
    }

    var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pix = imgd.data;

    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += (4)) {
        var all = pix[i] + pix[i + 1] + pix[i + 2];
        data[j++] = all / 40;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: so...did you find a solution? I´d be very much interested...I thougth about generalizing the lines along the grid vertices of the plane, essentially creating 'steps'...but then there are steps. raycasting should actually at least work to get interpolated values in between vertices though

Comment: @ThingumaBob I didn't end up having the path follow the terrain, I just plotted it at the highest point of the ground so that it wouldn't be hidden. My terrain wasn't very extreme so it worked for my purposes. I did end up getting rid of the raycasting however because it was VERY slow, and just ended up writing a function to find the grey value of the heightmap at the point where my objects will be plotted and using that corresponding height.